# Building a linked list java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to build a linked list in java according to the users's input.
However,it seems like the returned list I get is always referenced through the last node rather than the first one, which make it unworkable and unhelpful for me. I tries to solve it by making a reference to the first node-pos and returning the reference but it hasn't helped. for the input-1,2,3,4 for example, when trying to print the linked list it only prints 4.
The code

```
//input : The function gets values
//output : The function builds a linked list with the given numbers
public static Node<Integer> buildList(){
    int num;
    System.out.println("Enter values for the linked list(-999 to stop)");
    num=reader.nextInt();
    Node<Integer> list=new Node<Integer>(num);
    Node<Integer> pos=list;
    while(num!=-999){
        num=reader.nextInt();
        if(num!=-999){
            Node<Integer> newNode=new Node<Integer>(num);
            newNode.setNext(list);
            list=newNode;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Anyone knows what I did wrong?I'll be very grateful for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not adding new entries to the back.
The problem is with this

```
 Node<Integer> newNode=new Node<Integer>(num);
 newNode.setNext(list);
 list=newNode;
```

This code adds new nodes at the *head* of the linked list. At the end of the method, you return the reference *pos* which is the reference to the first node you inserted (the last node in the linked list). If you return the reference to the *newNode* at the end of the function, you would have

```
4->3->2->1
```

Here's a correct version that appends new nodes at the end of the linked list

```
 Node<Integer> newNode = new Node<Integer>(num);
 list.setNext(newNode); //Link previous node to current node.
 list = newNode;
```

**NOTE:** You have to take care of the case when the user enters -999 as the first number. In this case, you will still create a node (It's fine if that is what you want).

Comment: Hey thanks!You are totally right I don't know why I missed it and about checking the first number, well if that was a real program I would have taken care of that but this function is just a small part of a bigger one and it's really not the issue of what I was really trying to do it was just for the sake of a practice as long as i'm the only one entering values it's no a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rahter than using a Node object, why don't you use a [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) ?

Your code would look like :

```
//input : The function gets values
//output : The function builds a linked list with the given numbers
public static LinkedList<Integer> buildList(){
  int num = 0;      
  LinkedList<Integer> list = new  LinkedList<Integer>();
  while (num!=-999){
    System.out.println("Enter values for the linked list(-999 to stop)");
    num=reader.nextInt();
    if(num!=-999){
        list.add(num)
    }
  }
  return list;
}
```

Comment: What is the difference?I  haven't learnt to use the keyword LinkedList but rather just manually create singular nodes and link them together using the node class,i'm not sure my teacher would accept me using it.

Comment: There is no keyword LinkedList.

Answer (score 0):

At first you shouldn't use `Node<>` but `List<>`.
In your case it is `List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();`

The second problem is that you create a new list in all iterations. You should use `new` only one, before loop.

This code will work:

```
public static List<Integer> buildLitst() {
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
    System.out.println("Enter values for the linked list (-999 to stop)");
    int number = reader.nextInt();

    while (number != -999) {
        list.add(number);
        number = reader.nextInt();
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Doing what I did doesn't create a new list every iteration but a new node, However you are right that it would be easier to use a list in this case